# PowerShell Get-ADUser CSV export doesn't work

Tags: powershell

Could someone say what is wrong with my code?

```bsh
$csvimport = Import-Csv $csvfile -Delimiter ';'
$csvimport | ForEach-Object {
    foreach ($property in $_.PSObject.Properties) {
        if ($property.Name -contains "Vorname") {
            $vorname = $property.Value
        } else {
            $nachname = $property.Value
        }

        $user = Get-ADUser -Server $ADServer -Credential $GetAdminact -LDAPFilter (&(GivenName=$vorname)(Sn=$nachname)) -SearchBase $SearchBaseG

        $user |
            Select-Object @{Label = "Vorname";Expression = {$_.GivenName}},
                @{Label = "Nachname";Expression = {$_.Surname}},
                @{Label = "Telefon";Expression = {$_.telephoneNumber}} |
            Export-Csv -Path $csvfiles -NoTypeInformation
    }
}
```

I'm just trying to import names/surnames from a CSV. Then search for the user in Active Directory and generate a new CSV with their telephone number.

Comment: What is the output you get instead?

Comment: I dont get any output...

Comment: `$csvfile` is null among other variables so this code is not complete. Honestly... you need to debug this yourself a little bit. We have no source data and there is multiple avenues of potential failure here. The back and forth to find it is not fun when we have next to nothing as far as debugging information to start with.

Comment: is the csv being exported/created? Move `Export-Csv -Path $csvfiles -NoTypeInformation` to the end and pipe the outer foreach into it. Btw. I would recoment to use `-delimiter ';' ` in the export, too.

Comment: Thank you guys. It worked with pipe the outer foreach. And I also had another problem. Get-ADUser  -properties *  was not there so I cant get the telephone number from this command. Now it works. Thanks for help